# Postgres on amazon EC2 randomly disconnects

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, postgresql, django

I setup an amazon instance (medium ubuntu) with postgres server running on it. I'm connecting to that server from my personal pc, and while it generally works, I often get the following error (randomly):

```
OperationalError: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
```

My connectivity is fine, and the instance appears to be OK (it didn't crash or anything, and I can immediately reconnect and it works perfectly).

I look at postgres main log and see lines like these matching the disconnections:

```
2017-04-03 07:26:24.073 UTC [28918] testadmin@test_db FATAL:  connection to client lost
```

Which are not very helpful. How can I tackle this issue? Anyone have an idea of why this could happen with amazon instances? Its a simple medium instance no load balancer and no elastic IP (I connect via the public DNS of the instance).

Thanks!

Comment: PS. please don't comment about how I need to switch to RDS instead of putting postgres on an EC2..  While this advice is normally true, this is just a dev server and there are reasons why I want the postgres to run on it and not on designated RDS. Thanks!

Comment: Is the connection idle for extended periods before this occurs?

Comment: @Jason no, it happens randomly even while doing queries etc.

Comment: @Ness You can also check if there is any MaxConnections limit set and try increasing it.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with MySQL, although that appears to be related to an idle timeout....

Comment: @Chandan Didn't help :/ Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @RonenNess i hope this issue is resolved. If yes, can you tell me how you resolved it